# Is it possible to connect to the main net through the web ide?

Tags: cleos, mainnet

I'm learning how to navigate my way around with Cleos on the Web IDE release by B1 late last year. I know it spins up a personal chain but is there a way to connect to the public chain and publish a token contract on a main net account?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cleos` from a terminal command line, then you can publish to multiple different chains by using the `-u` flag, followed by a specific API endpoint.

For example, if you want to connect to the EOS Mainnet via the greymass endpoint, you would do:

`cleos -u https://eos.greymass.com ...`